# Want to click on download button from tableau dashboard using excel vba

Tags: tableau-api, automaton

I want click on download button from table dashboard using excel vba.

I tried tried elementbyclassname, elementbytagname but no success.

Source something like below

div classname, role="button" aria-label

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to add some code that you tried (maybe you just forgot?) so that we can help you.

Comment: Code is something like this.